# S_ISDIR and S_ISREG undeclared despite including the <sys/stat.h> header

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, stat

I am using the "S_ISDIR" and "S_ISREG" but am getting an error that they are undeclared. I tried using it in macOS(using S_IFDIR and S_IFREG) and it worked but not in linux terminal.

```
error: ‘S_ISDIR’ undeclared (first use in this function)  
error: ‘S_ISREG’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘S_ISDIR’?
```

```
struct stat s;
if(stat(fileName, &s) == 0 )
{
    if( s.st_mode & S_ISDIR )
    {
        return false;
    }
    else if( s.st_mode & S_ISREG )
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
else
{
    return false;
}
return false;
```

Comment: Your error messages refer to `S_ISDIR` and `S_ISREG`, but your code uses `S_IFDIR` and `S_IFREG`. Please show us the code corresponding to the error messages.

Comment: @zwol I have changed the code. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using the macros incorrectly.  They're function-like macros which accept the mode as a parameter:

```
if( S_ISDIR(s.st_mode) )
{
    return false;
}
else if( S_ISREG(s.st_mode) )
{
    return true;
}
else
{
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Note that it is impossible for `S_ISDIR(x)` and `S_ISREG(x)` to be true at the same time, so this could be simplified to `return !!S_ISREG(s.st_mode)`.

Answer (score 1):

You may be wondering why your original code, with `S_IFREG` and `S_IFDIR`, worked on one operating system but not another.  This is because the `S_IFxxx` constants are optional in some revisions of the POSIX standard (this is the standard that specifies the contents of `sys/stat.h`).

The `S_ISxxx` function-like macros are required to be available, so it's better to use them when you can, but sometimes using the `S_IFxxx` constants can make one's code much clearer.  They are macros, so you can test for their presence with `#ifdef S_IFREG` (if `S_IFREG` is available, it's safe to assume the others are as well).

Some operating systems don't provide the `S_IFxxx` constants by default, but do if you put `#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700` above all of your `#include` lines.  Linux is not *normally* one of those operating systems, but it becomes one of those operating systems if you use `-ansi` or `-std=cNN` on the compiler command line.  (N.B. for reasons too complicated to get into here, it is usually a mistake to use those switches instead of `-std=gnuNN`.)